# Android App crashes after integrating Google Play Services for AdMob using Pygame Subset for Android

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

i'm using **Pgs4a** (Pygame Subset for Android) to build my app. This works fine, until:
Recently i integrated the **Google Play Services** into my app for using **Admob**, but unfortunately my app crashes as soon as i launch it.

I already asked in *Google Group* for Admob, which recommended me to ask for help here. I also saw some posts here, but didn't solve my problem.

Here is, what i think, is the important part of my *logcat.log*

```
E/dalvikvm( 7969): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libsdl_mixer.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__gnu_thumb1_case_sqi" referenced by "libsdl_mixer.so"...
W/dalvikvm( 7969): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417f5da0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-817
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969): Process: com.myapp, PID: 7969
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__gnu_thumb1_case_sqi" referenced by "libsdl_mixer.so"...
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969):    at org.renpy.android.PythonActivity.run(PythonActivity.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7969):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/ActivityManager(  704):   Force finishing activity com.myapp/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
```

The *libsdl_mixer.so* is inside my *pygs4a/libs/armeabi* folder, if that helps.

Have you any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

I work on Windows 7 by the way.

Any help is much appreciated :)